# Importing a same variable from multiple libraries from different folder

Tags: python, loops, variables, import

I have a folder which contains .py scripts and each contains a same variable which I need in other script if that certain script is used from that folder.

- folder_x

  - main.py
  - folder_y

    - script1.py
    - script2.py
    - script3.py

So all the scripts are not used at the same time just one of them.

I found this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/35524184/5708537
And it works well but I have to list all the scripts manually.
I thought that I automate this and make a list of the files, and strip down the .py ending:

```
path = '/home/folder_x/folder_y'
files = os.listdir(path)
module_list = [i for i in files if i.endswith('.py')]
module_list = [os.path.splitext(x)[0] for x in module_list]
```

Works like a charm.

But this part of the code still thinks that the scripts are in folder_x

```
variables = {}
for mod_name in module_list:
mod = import_module(mod_name)
variables[mod_name] = getattr(mod, 'var')
```

So how can I tell to that the scripts are in folder_y and take that variable from those?

Or is there a better way to list scripts/modules from another folder, and get a variable from each of those?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import your own `.py`, just place them in the same directory as the program that is calling it. For example:

`from mymodule import *`

This lets you run all functions and methods in that file.

Comment: Yes I know that, but I wanna keep things separated.